# Argparse из терминала

Tags: python, linux, argparse

Никак не могу понять, как использовать argparse для вызова команд (написанных функций) из терминала линукс. Надо написать код на питоне, функции которого можно вызывать из термиала. Имею на данный момент такой тестовый код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse 

def print_xy(args):
    print(args.x * args.y)

def print_z(args):
    print(args.z)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('print_xy')
parser_foo.add_argument('x', type=int, default=1)
parser_foo.add_argument('y', type=float)
parser_foo.set_defaults(func=print_xy)

parser_bar = subparsers.add_parser('print_z')
parser_bar.add_argument('z')
parser_bar.set_defaults(func=print_z)
options = parser.parse_args()

if options.print_xy:
    print_xy(args)
elif options.print_z:
    print_z(args)
```

Хочется, чтобы при вызове в терминале линукс

```
./test.py print_xy 1 2
```

выводилось 2 (то есть x * y), а при вызове

```
./test.py print_z 10
```

выводилось 10 (то есть z).
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Примеры приветствуются.
P.S. Документацию читал, но там нет примера для вызова команд прямо из терминала

Comment: А у вас что выводится? Раз привели код, приведите и текущее поведение кода, а не только желаемое, так нам проще будет разбираться.

Comment: Этот код работает с ошибкой 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'print_xy'

Comment: Сделайте `add_subparsers(dest='action')` и проверяйте что-то вроде `if options.action == 'print_xy'`

Comment: зачем сабпарсеры? тут же `op *args`

Answer (score 3):

```
import argparse

def print_xy(arg):
    """ calculate multiplication x and y
    """
    print (arg[0]*arg[1])

def print_z(arg):
    """ simple print Z
    """
    print(arg[0])

calculator={'print_xy':print_xy, 'print_z':print_z}

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('command', help='may be print_xy or print_z')
parser.add_argument('integers', nargs='+',help='one or more integers numbers', type=int)
args=parser.parse_args()

calculator[args.command](args.integers)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--xy", nargs='*')
parser.add_argument("--z")
args, leftovers = parser.parse_known_args()

if args.xy is not None:
    print(int(args.xy[0]) * int(args.xy[1]))

elif args.z is not None:
    print(args.z)
```

- [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34989313/12785139)
- [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('command', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()


def print_xy(x, y):
    return print(int(x) * int(y))


def print_z(z):
    return print(z)


print_xy(args.command[1], args.command[2]) if args.command[0] == 'print_xy' and len(args.command) == 3 else (
    print_z(args.command[1]) if args.command[0] == 'print_z' and len(args.command) == 2 else print('error'))
```

Comment: Это явно не соответстует тому, что хочет автор `./test.py print_xy 1 2`

Comment: эм, а в чём сложность автору заменить мои --xy на свой -print_xy?

Comment: `print_xy` и `-print_xy` это всё ещё разные вещи, работающие принципиально разным образом

Answer (score 0):

По поводу ошибки - тут неправильное использование под if в конце. Функция [уже сохранена](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults) в опцию `func`. Её надо только достать из опций: [смотри пример номер 5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers)

Вместо последней конструкции надо

```
options.func(args)
```

По тому, что есть в вопросе, больше подходит обычный парсер с одним позиционном аргументом и списком параметров:

```python
import argparse

def print_xy(x,y):
    print(x * y)

def print_z(z):
    print(z)
    
 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('operation')
parser.add_argument('args', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+')

options = parser.parse_args()

func = locals().get(options.operation)
if callable(func):
    func(*options.args)
else:
    print('operation not found')
```

Но тут не сделаешь *красивую справку*

Answer (score -1):

А зачем здесь вообще argparse ?! TS не собирается использовать в командной строке ни '-' ни '--'. Здесь **нет** параметров! И работать в данном случае, нужно через *argc* и *argv*. Как-то так:

```
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == 'print_xy':
    x = int(sys.argv[2]) * int(sys.argv[3])
    print(x)
    exit(0)
     
if sys.argv[1] == 'print_z':
    x = int(sys.argv[2])
    print(x)
    exit(0)

print('Ошибка в записи команды:',  sys.argv[2])
```